# IE's "Object doesn't support this property or method" on slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

this seems to be a common problem which I have no idea how to solve.

So, I have a bunch of `<div>`'s whose id I decided for some reason to store in an array defined like

```
buttons = ["news", "info", "prog", "evnt"];
```

So one of the ways I use to get to slide them down is the following:

```
for (var i in buttons) $("#" + buttons[i]).slideDown ();
```

I also use this in the code:

```
for (var i in buttons)
   $("#" + buttons[i]).css ({display: "block"});
```

Neither, if the buttons are not visible, works (on IE 7 and 8), I get the usual "Object doesn't support this property or method" AFTER those blocks. Any ideas?

I also get a weird "unrecognized expression" error about jQuery, which confuses me.

Comment: Don't use `for in` to iterate arrays.

Comment: I HONESTLY CAN'T BELIEVE THAT WAS THE ACTUAL PROBLEM!! it solved it, why doesn't it work? why does it work on chrome/firefox/etc.?

Answer (score 0):

several little things:

- 1 - you can always **append** on the selector

  `$("#news, #info, #prog, #evnt").slideDown();`
- 2 - always use a **sequential `for` loop**

  `for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
     // do something
  }`
- 3 - when hiding, if you're using jQuery, **why not [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)**?

  `for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
     $("#" + buttons[i]).hide();
  }`

Comment: i'm still puzzled as to why `for in` behaves differently

Comment: it's a perfect viable question to answer, witch has already been [answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/28004)